# PHP preg_replace html comments with empty space

Tags: php, html, regex, comments, preg-replace

I have a bit of php code like this:

```
$test = "<!--my comment goes here--> Hello World";
```

Now i want to strip the whole html comment from the string, i know i need to use preg_replace, but now sure on the regex to go in there. 
Can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$str=<<<'EOF'
<!--my comment goes here--> Hello World"
blah  <!-- my another
comment here --> blah2
end
EOF;

$r="";
$s=explode("-->",$str);
foreach($s as $v){
  $m=strpos($v,'<!--');
  if($m!==FALSE){
   $r.=substr($v,1,$m);
  }
}
$r.=end($s);
print $r."\n";
```

output

```
$ php test.php
Hello World"
blah  < blah2
end
```

Or if you must preg_replace,

```
preg_replace("/<!--.*?-->/ms","",$str);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
preg_replace('/<!--(.*)-->/Uis', '', $html)
```

Will remove every html comment contained in the `$html` string. Hope this helps!

Comment: When I used this code, it would also remove content that showed up between 2 separate HTML comment blocks. I think the U modifier might make the expression "greedy".

Instead of trying to tweak this, I used the expression in [ghostdog74's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499137/115432) instead which had .*? instead of (.*) and used /ms instead of /Uis

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 preg_replace('~<!--.+?-->~s', '', $html);
```

Comment: This is the only good answer on this whole page. I have added a "m" modifier too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$test = "<!--my comment goes here--> Hello World";
echo  preg_replace('/\<.*\> / ','',$test);
?>
```

Use the following code for global replace:

```
<?php
$test = "<!--my comment goes here--> Hello World <!--------welcome-->welcome";
echo  preg_replace('/\<.*?\>/','',$test);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those will only work if you dont have 2 comments with content between like ...

```
<!--comment--> Im a goner <!--comment-->
```

You need ...

```
//preg_replace('/<!--[^>]*-->/', '', $html); // <- this is incorrect see ridgrunners comments below, you really need ...
preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/', '', $html);
```

The [^>] matches anything but > so as to not go past the matching > seeking the next.
I havent tested phps regex but it claims to be perl regex which is by default 'greedy' and will match as much as possible.

But since youre matching a specifically named placeholder you just need the entire string and to use str_replace() instead.

```
str_replace('<!--my comment goes here-->', $comment, $html);
```

And, rather than replacing placeholders in a file just make it a php file and write out the variables.

:)

Comment: No, a `>` is allowed and is perfectly valid inside a comment. The `.*?` lazy-dot-star is actually the better expression in this case (and does not remove the `"Im a goner"` text as you infer),

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you

```
preg_replace("/<\!--.*?-->/s","",$html);
```